# VIMEO API Search private videos

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, vimeo-api

I have a problem with the Vimeo API, and the way that they show their documentation gave me a headache. 
Look, I need to make a request to the api to retrieve information of private videos. I have a code to do this, but with normal videos:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + x.val() + '.json',
   jsonp: 'callback',
   dataType: 'jsonp'
 }).done(function(data){
  $('#vimeo #nameVideo').attr('value', data[0].title);
  $('#vimeo #descriptionVideo').attr('value', data[0].description);
});
```

And it works!
So, the problem is: I don't know where, or how, put the Authentication info to access to the private videos. I created the app, and Vimeo gave the Client Identifier, Client Secrets and Acces Token with the scopes public and private.

I use vimeo API Playground to make test and this is what I want:
[Vimeo Playground Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8xMz.jpg)

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a good time of read and investigation, I have solved my problem. 
First, I found this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vimeo
Vimeo have a package of npm, so, the first think what we need to do is install it with

```
npm install vimeo
```

Then in the respective router controller, in my case videosdb.js, create de required variables

```
var Vimeo = require('vimeo').Vimeo;
//Put the data obtained when you create the app in developer.vimeo.com
var vimeoVids = new Vimeo('<Client Identifier>', '<Client Secret>', '<Access Token>');
```

And with that you can do whatever you want with the Vimeo Api.
In my case, retrieve the info of the private videos of an especific user.

```
vimeoVids.request({
  path: '/users/<User Name>/videos/<Video ID>'
}, function(e, data){
   if(e){
     console.log(e);
   }
   res.send(data);
 })
```

})

Comment: Just to ask out of curiosity: does that mean you are using your "client secret" within your Javascript files?

Comment: This package is meant for node js not the browser, you shouldn't expose your secret publicly

Answer (score 3):

According to the [API docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication) you have to send the auth headers in the request.

You first have to `POST https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/access_token` to get the access token.

Once you have that you can make an ajax call with the authorization header:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/:id',
   headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token 
   }
 }).done(function(data) {
      $('#vimeo #nameVideo').attr('value', data[0].title);
      $('#vimeo #descriptionVideo').attr('value', data[0].description);  
  });
```

Comment: Is it normal to get a 404 for a private video that I just created but didn't finish transcoding?

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is for the simple API, a totally different system from the API playground. You can tell by comparing the urls you use. The new API is documented here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api